# Как можно реализовать в html и css. Фото прилагаю

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно реализовать в html и css. Фото прилагаю.

Comment: просто блок квадратный развернуть и загнать в угол а у родителя скрыть всё что вылазиет

Comment: какой блок вогнать?

Comment: я ответом написал - посмотри

Comment: спасибо я все понял

Comment: галочка рядом с ответом

Comment: смысле не понял "галочка рядом с ответом"

Comment: если ответ устроил его надо отметить  решением

Comment: спасибо я все понял

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если что-то не ясно, - спрашивай, я поясню.

Вот здесь => https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/ymerEL можешь тренироваться

```css
.item {
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
  height: 320px;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item:after {
  content: "";
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -75px;
  top: -75px;
  background: tomato;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.item span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 30px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <span>release</span>
</div>
```